# Is it possible to use if statement in a class definition?

Tags: c++

I am relatively new to programming in C++ and therefore do not know how much you can do with a class. However I was wondering if I could create a class in a header file and use if statements in that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use if statements in inline member functions of that class. You cannot use if statements outside of functions. (The "statement" gives it away. Statements can only appear inside functions.)